# Why is JupyterLab not rendering my math in Markdown properly?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter-lab, mathjax

I have been trying to write mathematical expressions in JupyterLab but it does not render properly. It is only when I shut down the window and reopen it do I see that it has rendered correctly. Otherwise it just translates from TeX style code to LaTeX style code. I'm running an m1 mac and Safari does display MathJax correctly.

In the first image you see what I get when I type it out, in the second image you see what happens when I reopen the notebook after closing Jupyter(what I should be getting).

What I get:
[image]

What I should be getting:
[image]

Comment: This would be a bug. This is way too little information to event attempt to reproduce it (what is the JupyterLab version, code that you type in the markdown cell) and bugs are best reported on https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab, not on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Have tried `$...$` for inline math mode?

Comment: @sebo1234 yes I did. I'm running JupyterLab version 3.4.4 and Python version 3.9.13.

Comment: @krassowski 3.4.4 and Python 3.9.13. Thanks, I'll do that then. :)